Google open images v7 dataset download for YOLOv8
How to download images and labels form google open images v7 for training an YOLOv8 model?
I have tried cloning
!git clone https://github.com/NanoCode012/OIDv6_ToolKit_Download_Open_Images_Support_Yolo_Format.git
!pip3 install -r /content/OIDv6_ToolKit_Download_Open_Images_Support_Yolo_Format/requirements.txt

!mkdir OID
!mkdir OID/Dataset

classes = 'Apple Orange'
samples = 100
!python /content/OIDv6_ToolKit_Download_Open_Images_Support_Yolo_Format/main.py downloader --classes {classes} --type_csv train --limit {samples}

I saw it from web was the easiest way to do so but the labels dimensions are improper.

What is the problem with this code? Have you got the necessary files but with annotations in a different from the yolov8 format (if so, what is the exact format)? Or the files were not downloaded at all? The script you use is for Open Images V6, not V7, as I understand.

You can try this
from ultralytics.utils import LOGGER, SETTINGS, Path, is_ubuntu, get_ubuntu_version
from ultralytics.utils.checks import check_requirements, check_version

check_requirements("fiftyone")
if is_ubuntu() and check_version(get_ubuntu_version(), ">=22.04"):
    # Ubuntu>=22.04 patch https://github.com/voxel51/fiftyone/issues/2961#issuecomment-1666519347
    check_requirements("fiftyone-db-ubuntu2204")

import fiftyone as fo
import fiftyone.zoo as foz
import warnings

name = "open-images-v7"
fraction = 1.0  # fraction of full dataset to use
LOGGER.warning("WARNING ⚠️ Open Images V7 dataset requires at least **561 GB of free space. Starting download...")
for split in "train", "validation":  # 1743042 train, 41620 val images
    train = split == "train"

    # Load Open Images dataset
    dataset = foz.load_zoo_dataset(
        name,
        split=split,
        label_types=["detections"],
        classes=["Human", "Dog"],  # Specify the classes you're interested in here
        label_types=["detections"],
        dataset_dir=Path(SETTINGS["datasets_dir"]) / "fiftyone" / name,
        max_samples=round((1743042 if train else 41620) * fraction),
    )

    # Define classes
    if train:
        classes = dataset.default_classes  # all classes
        # classes = dataset.distinct('ground_truth.detections.label')  # only observed classes

    # Export to YOLO format
    with warnings.catch_warnings():
        warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=UserWarning, module="fiftyone.utils.yolo")
        dataset.export(
            export_dir=str(Path(SETTINGS["datasets_dir"]) / name), dataset_type=fo.types.YOLOv5Dataset, label_field="ground_truth", split="val" if split == "validation" else split, classes=classes, overwrite=train
        )


